# Powershell If and ElseIf statements not working

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I am very new to Powershell and coding.  To my understanding, the input from a Read-Host cmdlet can be piped into a variable.  I would like prompt the user to enter a number greater than 5 If -gt 5 it Write-Host Yes elseif -lt 5 no.  For some reason no matter what number I select I get no.  If goes straight to elseif. Can anyone help?

```
$A = Read-Host "Enter number greater than 5"

If ($A -gt 5)
{
Write-Host "yes"
}
elseif ($A -lt 5)
{
Write-Host "no"
}
```

Comment: `Read-Host` gives you a string.  You're comparing two unlike types.  Consider this: `[int](Read-Host -Prompt 'message')`

Comment: Read-Host always creates a string variable. If you like to get a number you have to cast the variable explicitly as this like so `[INT]$A = Read-Host "Enter number greater than 5"` par example.

Answer (score 0):

Putting TheIncorrigible1s comment into a full example.

Read-Host takes the input as a string and cannot figure out if it is greater than or lower than another string.
example: Is Phone greater than Spectacles?

PowerShell is interpreting the input as "Is One greater than Seven?" and not "Is 1 greater than 7?"

Numbers vs words.

Adding the `[int]` in front of the `Read-Host` will convert the input into an integer. This means that if you try typing text, it will error out. It will only accept numerical input.

```
$A = [int](Read-Host "Enter number greater than 5")

If($A -gt 5) {
    "Yes" | Out-host
} elseif($A -lt 5) {
    "No" | Out-host
}
```

Note: I rather `Out-Host` instead of `Write-Host`. Each to their own though.

Comment: Thank you, Drew.  I understand your examples especially the words vs numbers one.  What is the benefit of Out-Host over Write-Host?